# WPF C# Binding Data from another Class

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm missing something simple or losing my mind.  I am trying to reuse a class for multiple pages in a WPF application and bind the properties to the pages that instance it.  I've tried setting the DataContext but I'm missing something.  I'm loading the StockAnalysis page and then creating instance of the PriceChart class (this is the class for reuse) and I want the properties set in the PriceChart class to be the data to bind to the Stock.xaml.cs page.  Even in setting the DataContext it is still looking for the StockAnalysis object.  Why?

Stock.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class StockAnalysis : Page
 {
     PriceChart PChart = new PriceChart();

     public StockAnalysis()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Load The Data
        List<Stock> HistoricalPrice = Database.GetPrices(ticker);

        //Create The Charts
        this.DataContext = PChart;
        PChart.ShowPriceChart(HistoricalPrice);
     }
 }
```

Stock.xaml (Look at the Last TexBlock for the Binding of "LastPrice")

```
    <Page x:Class="Stock.StockAnalysis"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
          xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stock"
          mc:Ignorable="d" 
          d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1200"
          Title="Stock Analysis">
                <StackPanel x:Name="LastClosePanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="5" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1,0,0,1" Style="{StaticResource LastCloseBackground}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LastCloseText" Foreground="OrangeRed" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,8">Last Close</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LastCloseBind" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LastPrice}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
   </Page>
```

PriceChart.cs  (This is where I assign "LastPrice" in hopes to bind it to the TextBlock in stock.xaml.cs)

```
public class PriceChart
{
    public string LastPrice { get; set; }
    
    public void ShowPriceChart(List<Stock> FullList)
    {
        LastPrice = FullList[0].LastPrice.ToString("C");
        //DO OTHER THINGS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `PriceChart` doesn't implement any change notification. With the current code, this is how things will go when `StockAnalysis` gets created:

1. `InitializeComponent()` will create the `TextBlock`s and the binding. At this point, `DataContext` is `null`, so the binding will fail and the `TextBlock` stay empty.
2. `this.DataContext = PChart` will trigger a binding update (because `DataContext` is a `DependencyProperty`, which means it *does* support change notification). When the binding updates, it will pull the value of `LastPrice`, which is currently still empty.
3. `ShowPriceChart` will set the value of `LastPrice`, but because `PriceChart` doesn't support change notification, the binding doesn't know it needs to update, so the `TextBlock` stays empty.

To solve this, I would recomend your `PriceChart` implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface per this article: [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification).

(Technically, moving `PChart.ShowPriceChart(HistoricalPrice)` before `this.DataContext = PChart` would also "solve" the problem, but only if you never need to update the bindings again after initialization.)